# Why are some of the Lego bricks red in the Gringott's Vaults?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

I've been playing through some of the bonus levels in the Gringott's Vault, and noticed that the bricks in vaults 3, 7, and 9 are red, while all the other bricks are green. Is there a particular reason why three of them would be red? I though maybe it meant I couldn't complete them yet, but I've played through them and had no trouble completing them. Just wondering what the difference in color meant, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit obscure but the colour of the bricks seems to tell you what background the bonus level is using. All the bonus levels which are inside, with a stone floor use the red brick. All the bonus levels which are outside, with a grass floor use the green brick.

Answer (score -3):

From [this GameFAQs article](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/xbox360/960495-lego-harry-potter-years-1-4/answers/212186-more-than-1-red-brick-at-once), It appears that the different colored bricks can be collected to gain additional achievements.

Comment: The linked question has absolutely nothing to do with this. It is talking about the score multiplier red brickes (which provide for x2, x4, x6, x8, and x10) and that possibility to combine them together. My question is about the bricks representing the bonus levels in the vault and why some of them are different colors.